# "Culposo" e "doloso": porque o homicídio não intencional é chamado de "homicídio culposo"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, ambiguidades

Toda vez que aparece no noticiário, o repórter diz:

> [...] homicídio culposo, quando não há a intenção de matar.

Ou então:

> [...] homicídio doloso, quando há a intenção de matar.

A impressão deixada no primeiro exemplo soa tão contraditória, que a explicação faz-se necessária.

Alguém saberia explicar os porquês?

Comment: O culposo realmente me parece contraditório, já o doloso não me parece nada, rs..

Comment: Também já me tinha perguntado porque é que o Oscar Pistorious tinha sido condenado por "culpable homicide" quando o tribunal decidiu que não havia provas de crime intencional. Não sabia que os termos eram os mesmos em português.

Comment: @Math Melhorei a escrita. Obrigado!

Comment: Este @Math é danado, heim. Eu tinha deixado como estava :)

Comment: Hahaha. Só falei a minha impressão :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solução do paradoxo é que [***doloso*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/doloso) significa  ***com dolo***, e ao contrário do que possa parecer não tem que ver com dor. Cito a definição de [***dolo*** no Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/dolo):

> (1) Ação fraudulenta de alguém para com outrem; FRAUDE; LOGRO; MÁ-FÉ.
>   (2) Jur. Intenção consciente de induzir alguém a cometer ou manter erro, com prejuízo para ele [Antôn.: boa-fé, correção.]
>   (3) Jur. Intenção consciente de cometer ou assumir o risco de ato criminoso.

Logo, homicídio *doloso* é homicídio intencional. O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) traz também estas definições e explica que *dolo* vem do latim *dŏlus*, que significava ‘destreza, esperteza, artifício, engano, logro, embuste’; por sua vez, o latim é adaptação do grego *dólus*, ‘logro, ardil’.

Ainda segundo o Houaiss, *doloso* tem também o siginificado mais geral, não jurídico, de ‘enganador, pérfido’, que também já vem do latim *dolōsus*, que significava ‘manhoso, astucioso, enganador’. Contrastar com *dor* e *doloroso*, do latim *dolor* e *dolorōsus* (Houaiss).

Por seu lado, ***culpa*** não implica intenção de causar dano. O [Aulete digital define ***culpa***](http://www.aulete.com.br/culpa) como:

> (1) Responsabilidade atribuída a algo ou alguém por mal, dano ou prejuízo causado.
>   (6) Jur. Falta, delito que fere os princípios do dever jurídico, cometida por ação ou omissão.
>   (7) Jur. Ato voluntário que tenha efeito lesivo sobre os direitos de outrem.

No significado (7), o ato é voluntário, mas não implica que o efeito lesivo tenha sido intencional.

Answer (score 3):

**Dolo** e **negligência** são as duas modalidades de culpa, isto é, existe culpa dolosa e culpa negligente, existindo ainda subdivisões dentro de cada categoria (dolo direto, eventual e necessário e negligência simples e qualificada/grosseira). Na formulação do Código Penal português (artigos 14 e 15):

> Artigo 14.º
> *Dolo*
>
> 1. [*direto*] Age com dolo quem, representando um facto que preenche um tipo de crime, actuar com intenção de o realizar.
> 2. [*necessário*] Age ainda com dolo quem representar a realização de um facto que preenche um tipo de crime como consequência necessária da sua conduta.
> 3. [*eventual*] Quando a realização de um facto que preenche um tipo de crime for representada como consequência possível da conduta, há dolo se o agente actuar conformando-se com aquela realização.
>
> Artigo 15.º
> *Negligência*
>
> Age com negligência quem, por não proceder com o cuidado a que, segundo as circunstâncias, está obrigado e de que é capaz:
>
> a. Representar como possível a realização de um facto que preenche um tipo de crime mas actuar sem se conformar com essa realização; ou
> b. Não chegar sequer a representar a possibilidade de realização do facto.

Na lei penal portuguesa, contrariamente à lei civil, só os factos praticados com dolo ou, nos casos especialmente previstos na lei, com negligência, podem ser punidos (art. 13.º do CP).

O ***homicídio doloso*** é por conseguinte a forma mais grave. ***Homicídio culposo*** é o homícidio meramente negligente.

Comment: Excelente contribuição! Acredito que acertou em cheio ao trazer a terminologia `negligência`.